# Using Event Hubs binding for Azure Functions with managed identities?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

I'm trying to find information on how to set up the connection strings in a Function App binding so that the app uses managed identities to access Event Hubs and other resources. I'm able to use managed identities in other applications by getting an access token as described in the documentation.

How does this work in Function Apps that take a configuration variable name for connections settings on resource bindings?

Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer should be we can't use Managed identities access token in Function bindings.

[Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#trigger---configuration) requires the connection string to the event hub's namespace for event hub bindings, the token got using Managed identities is invalid. In Azure Function, we use the access token in same the way you have done in other applications, here's the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity#obtaining-tokens-for-azure-resources).

Comment: Is it still the case ? Is there something planned to support Managed identities in Function bindings ?

Comment: I found a feature request here. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/37907848-support-for-azure-managed-service-identities-in-ev. I did upvote in feature request so that Microsoft team can consider and plan for work.

Answer (score 2):

I tested it today to connect to Service Bus queue. The connection string is:

```
Endpoint=sb://<service-bus-resource>.servicebus.windows.net;Authentication=Managed Identity;
```

I found it on this blog:
https://blog.darkloop.com/post/using-service-app-managed-identity-with-azure-functions-service-bus-bindings. I didn't need to do anything special as my project is using `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 4.1.1`.

But please look at comments in this blog post - some say it will not work with consumption plan. Another potential issue is mentioned here:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/37907848-support-for-azure-managed-service-identities-in-ev

> Please note that the behavior captured in the post by Arturo was
> considered unintentional from the SDK team and removed in a later
> version update. We are working with them to make this formally
> supported, but right now the instructions in that post may no longer
> work.

So I'm not sure if one should use it or not.

Answer (score 0):

full support for managed identities is now in beta https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/introducing-the-new-azure-function-extension-libraries-beta/ leveraging Azure.Identity library